# Which expression best represents the error in the prime number theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers

From prime number theorem, we kmow that $$\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{log(x)}$$

[Fig 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SQga.png)

As you can see, in this graph, $\pi(x)-\frac{x}{log(x)}$ is increasing. My question is is there any function which best represents this curve?

Comment: Check out the lower-order terms in the [asymptotic series for the logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $1979$, Hardy and Wright gave in *"An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers"*
$$\pi(x)=-1+\sum_{n=3}^x \Bigg[(n-2)!-n \left\lfloor \frac{(n-2)!}{n}\right\rfloor\Bigg]$$ which is exact for $x>3$.

For a discussion about bounds, have a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373737/bounds-for-prime-counting-function).

I do not remember where I saw the approximation
$$\pi(x) \sim \text{li}\left(x+\sqrt{x}\right)-\text{li}\left(\sqrt{x}+2\right)$$ where  $ \text{li}(k)$ is the Eulerian logarithmic integral.

For $x=10^k$ some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 4 & 4 \\
 2 & 25 & 25 \\
 3 & 168 & 168 \\
 4 & 1226 & 1229 \\
 5 & 9586 & 9592 \\
 6 & 78522 & 78498 \\
 7 & 664651 & 664579 \\
 8 & 5761506 & 5761455 \\
 9 & 50847327 & 50847534 \\
 10 & 455050328 & 455052511 \\
 11 & 4118051515 & 4118054813 \\
 12 & 37607907844 & 37607912018 \\
 13 & 346065523621 & 346065536839 \\
 14 & 3204941710984 & 3204941750802 \\
 15 & 29844570438537 & 29844570422669 \\
 16 & 279238341200688 & 279238341033925 \\
 17 & 2623557156605758 & 2623557157654233 \\
 18 & 24739954282968651 & 24739954287740860 \\
 19 & 234057667296624319 & 234057667276344607 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$